I want to filter certain dates in MongoDB and React
In this code, I am helping a company with the filters and I specifically have a struggle filtering out by the date type. Here is the order Router for the local SAP orders and specifically look at the createdAt variable, it is a Date type:
orderRouter.get(
  '/localSAPOrders/:query',
  isAuth,
  isAdmin,
  asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    //console.log('----')
    var totalCount = 200
    var query = JSON.parse(req.params.query)
    //console.log('query----->',query)
    //console.log('------------------------------------------------------',req.query,req.params,req.url,req.originalUrl,req.baseUrl);
    //var filter = { billToPartyID: null, orderIdSap: null,createdAt:null,totalPrice:null,purchaseOrder:null,trackingCode:null, orderStatusSap:null}
    var filterStr = '{'
    //console.log('q',query)
    if (
      query.orderIdSap != '' &&
      query.orderIdSap != null &&
      query.orderIdSap != undefined
    ) {
      //  filter.orderIdSap = query.orderIdSap
      filterStr += '"orderIdSap":"' + query.orderIdSap + '"'
    }
    if (
      query.billToPartyID != '' &&
      query.billToPartyID != null &&
      query.billToPartyID != undefined
    ) {
      //   filter.billToPartyID = '/.*' + query.billToPartyID + '.*/i'
      if (filterStr != '{') filterStr += ','
      filterStr += '"billToPartyID":"' + query.billToPartyID + '"'
    }
    if (
      query.createdAt && isValidDate(query.createdAt)
    ) {
      if (filterStr != '{') filterStr += ','
      let startOfDay = new Date(query.createdAt);
      startOfDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      let endOfDay = new Date(query.createdAt);
      endOfDay.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
      filterStr += `"createdAt": { "$gte": "${startOfDay.toISOString()}", "$lt": "${endOfDay.toISOString()}" }`;
  console.log(query.createdAt)
  console.log(filterStr)
  
  }
    if (
      query.totalPrice != '' &&
      query.totalPrice != null &&
      query.totalPrice != undefined
    ) {
      //filter.totalPrice = query.totalPrice
      if (filterStr != '{') filterStr += ','
      filterStr += '"totalPrice":"' + query.totalPrice + '"'
    }
    if (
      query.purchaseOrder != '' &&
      query.purchaseOrder != null &&
      query.purchaseOrder != undefined
    ) {
      //filter.purchaseOrder = '/.*' + query.purchaseOrder + '.*/i'
      if (filterStr != '{') filterStr += ','
      filterStr += '"purchaseOrder":"' + query.purchaseOrder + '"'
    }
    if (
      query.trackingCode != '' &&
      query.trackingCode != null &&
      query.trackingCode != undefined
    ) {
      //filter.trackingCode = '/.*' + query.trackingCode + '.*/i'
      if (filterStr != '{') filterStr += ','
      filterStr += '"trackingCode":"' + query.trackingCode + '"'
    }
    if (
      query.orderStatusSap != '' &&
      query.orderStatusSap != null &&
      query.orderStatusSap != undefined
    ) {
      //filter.orderStatusSap = '/.*' + query.orderStatusSap + '.*/i'
      if (filterStr != '{') filterStr += ','
      filterStr += '"orderStatusSap":"' + query.orderStatusSap + '"'
    }
    //console.log('query2----->',query)
    filterStr += '}'
    //    console.log(filterStr)
    const metZeroTotal = await OrderModel.find({
      totalPrice: 0,
      'orderItems.price': { $ne: 0 },
      orderItems: { $ne: [] },
    })
    var totalPrice = 0
    for (var o = 0; o < metZeroTotal.length; o++) {
      totalPrice = 0
      for (var oi = 0; oi < metZeroTotal[o].orderItems.length; oi++) {
        totalPrice += metZeroTotal[o].orderItems[oi].price
      }
      metZeroTotal[o].totalPrice = totalPrice
      metZeroTotal[o].save()
    }
    console.log(filterStr)
    const localsapordersAdmin = await OrderModel.find(JSON.parse(filterStr))
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .sort({ orderIdSap: -1 })
      .limit(totalCount)

    // console.log('localsaporders-----',localsapordersAdmin.length)
    res.send(localsapordersAdmin)
  })
)

Here is the front end for this program:
  const [queryDate, setCDate] = useState('')
 var urlsearch=new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  var query=urlsearch.has('query')?urlsearch.get('query'):JSON.stringify({})
  const { data: sap_orders, isLoading , error, refetch} = useGetLocalSAPOrdersQuery(query)
function remInvoices(){
query=JSON.stringify({
        

        orderIdSap:queryId,
        billToPartyID:queryBillTo,
        createdAt: queryDate,
        totalPrice: queryPrice,
        purchaseOrder: queryPO,
        trackingCode: queryTrack,
        orderStatusSap: queryStatus.includes('--Select--') ? '' : queryStatus

        
      })
      console.log(queryDate);
      window.location.href=query ? `/admin/orders/?query=${query}` : '/admin/orders'
  }
 <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>CUSTOMER</th>
              <th>ORDERED DATE</th>
              <th>TOTAL</th>
              <th>PURCHASE ORDER</th>
              <th>TRACKING NUMBER</th>
              <th>STATUS</th>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          
            <tr>
            <td><input className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)} type='number'/></td>
            <td><input className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setBillTo(e.target.value)} /></td>
            <td><input className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setCDate(e.target.value)} type='date'/></td>
            <td><input className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} type="number"/></td>
            <td><input className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setPO(e.target.value)} /></td>
            <td><input className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setTrack(e.target.value)} /></td>
            <td><select className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)} id='inv-status'><option value=''>--Select--</option><option value='1'>Open</option><option value='2'>In Process</option><option value='3'>Completed</option><option value='4'>In Preparation</option></select></td>
            
            <td><Button className='fas fa-search' onClick={remInvoices}></Button><Button onClick={()=>window.location.href='/admin/orders'} className='fas fa-recycle'></Button></td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {sap_orders!.map((order) => (
              <tr key={order._id} className={order.orderFromSAP?'sapOrder':'localOrder'}>
                <td>{order.orderIdSap}</td>
                <td>{order.billToPartyID}</td>
                <td>{order.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                <td>{USDollar.format(order.totalPrice)}</td>
                <td>{order.purchaseOrder}</td>
                <td>{(order.trackingCode!=undefined && order.trackingCode!=null && order.trackingCode!='')?order.trackingCode.split(',').map((inv_no)=>inv_no?.indexOf('1Z')>-1?<span><a href={upsval+inv_no.replace(/^0+/i,'')} target="__blank"> {inv_no.replace(/^0+/i,'')}</a><br/></span>:order.shippingMethod?.indexOf('FEDEX')>-1?<span><a href={fedexval+inv_no.replace(/^0+/i,'')} target="__blank"> {inv_no.replace(/^0+/i,'')}</a><br/></span> :<span><a href={upsval+inv_no.replace(/^0+/i,'')} target="__blank"> {inv_no.replace(/^0+/i,'')}</a><br/></span> ):''}</td>
                <td>{order.orderStatusSap=='1'?'Open':order.orderStatusSap=='2'?'In Process':order.orderStatusSap=='3'?'Completed':order.orderStatusSap=='4'?'In Preparation':'--Select--'}</td>
                <td><Button
                    type="button"
                    variant="light"
                    onClick={() => {
                      navigate(`/order/${order._id}`)
                    }}
                  >
                    Details
                  </Button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>

I have tried various things so far including: Not Using the query, using the $gte and $lt functions, and I can't display the orders which happened at a specific date.

Can we see a sample document?  Specifically, what is the datatype of the createAt field in the documents in the database?

Please provide some sample input document and query parameters. Remove the second code block, it is not relevant for your question.

{
"objectIdSap": "8B0D4884F1DC1EDF8586E2E643D053D1",
"orderItems": [],
"createdAt": {"$date": "2024-05-17T10:20:20.000Z"
},
"paymentMethod": "ByInvoice",
"shippingMethod": "",
"purchaseOrder": "",
"trackingCode": "",
"itemsPrice": 6,
"shippingPrice": 0,
"taxPrice": 0,
"totalPrice": 6,
"isPaid": false,
"orderFromSAP": true,
"isDelivered": false,
"orderIdSap": 30254,
"orderStatusSap": "3",
"billToPartyID": "1002887",
"syncedWithTTRX": false,
"updatedAt": {
"$date": "2024-07-10T22:06:17.520Z"
},
"__v": 1,
"shippingAddress": {}
}

Why do you create the query as JSON string? Why do you compare Date values with strings?
You can do much more elegant like this:
let filter = {};    
if (query.orderIdSap ?? '' != '') 
   filter.orderIdSap = query.orderIdSap;
if (query.billToPartyID ?? '' != '') 
   filter.billToPartyID = query.billToPartyID;
...    
let startOfDay = new Date(query.createdAt);
startOfDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
let endOfDay = new Date(query.createdAt);
endOfDay.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
filter.createdAt = { $gte: startOfDay, $lt: endOfDay };

const localsapordersAdmin = await OrderModel.find(filter);

or even shorter
let filter = {};    
for (let key of ['orderIdSap', 'billToPartyID', 'totalPrice', 'purchaseOrder', 'trackingCode', 'orderStatusSap']) {
   if (query[key] ?? '' != '') 
      filter[key] = query[key];
}
let startOfDay = new Date(query.createdAt);
startOfDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
let endOfDay = new Date(query.createdAt);
endOfDay.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
filter.createdAt = { $gte: startOfDay, $lt: endOfDay };
... 
const localsapordersAdmin = await OrderModel.find(filter);

Use JSON.stringify(filter) for debugging the generated query.
Two sort operations are pointless, I guess you are looking for this one:
const localsapordersAdmin = await OrderModel.find(filter)
  .sort({ createdAt: -1, orderIdSap: -1 })
  .limit(totalCount)

